# My wpf application can save a notepad file on the fixed path i provided in app.config as a key but i want it to be saved on the desktop of the user?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, filepath

```
private void WriteToFile(TextRange textRange)
    {
                  using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderpath"], true))
        {
            oWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
            oWriter.WriteLine(textRange.Text);
            oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
            oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
            oWriter.Write("$");
        }
        MessageBox.Show(folderpath);
    }
```

the folderpath in the code is a key in app.config with value="C:\Users\MyPC\Desktop\textfile.txt"

if i delete the key and initialize a string in the code, it shows an error of Value cannot be null.
Please help!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you are trying to initialize the string in code?

Comment: string folderpath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)+"textfile.txt";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory string returned from `Environment.GetFolderPath` does not include a trailing `/` so your resulting string ends up as: `C:\Users\User\Desktoptextfile.txt`

I would highly suggest using `Path.Combine()` to append the filename to the path which will prevent this from happening.

Ex:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "textfile.txt")
```

Full example with your code:

```
private void WriteToFile(TextRange textRange)
{
    string folderpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "textfile.txt");
    using (StreamWriter oWriter = new StreamWriter(folderpath, true))
    {
        oWriter.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
        oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
        oWriter.WriteLine(textRange.Text);
        oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
        oWriter.WriteLine("*****************************************************************************");
        oWriter.Write("$");
    }
    MessageBox.Show(folderpath);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i m still having problem. here is a screenshot http://s17.postimg.org/idnivs2lb/Capture.jpg

Comment: You need to remove `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderpath"]` and replace it with just `folderpath` otherwise you are telling it that there should be key in the app.config named the same as your filepath.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the change in the context of your code.

Comment: it worked sir! thanks a ton! I tried to vote the answer 'up', but my reputation level isn't allowing it.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad we got it sorted out :)